# How to find $\mathbb{P}(X<C)$ where both $X$ and $C$ are RVs and $X$ depends on another RV?

Tags: probability, distributions, joint-distribution

I have a scenario like the following:

1. $C$ is a random variable that follows $\operatorname{Uniform}(0, 3.5)$.
2. $T$ is a random variable with $\operatorname{Exponential}(\operatorname{mean}=3)$ for group 1 and $\operatorname{Exponential}(\operatorname{mean}=1.5)$ for group 2.
3. $X$ is a random variable with $\operatorname{Uniform}(0, 1)$ for group 1 and $\operatorname{Uniform}(1, T)$ for group 2.

I am struggling to calculate:

$$\mathbb{P}(X<C)=\int_0^{3.5}\int_0^{c}f_X(x)dxf_C(c)dc+\int_0^{3.5}\int_1^{c}f_X(x)dxf_C(c)dc$$

since for group 2, $X$ is dependent on $T$. Can someone help me find out the probability?

Comment: Why not work out the distribution of $X$?  That will place you in the standard (and elementary) situation of comparing two (presumably) independent random variables.

Comment: As noted by whuber, you need to express this probability in terms of the joint distribution of $(X,C,T)$ and integrate out all three rvs:$$P(X<C)=\int\int\int \mathbb{I}_{x<c} f(x,c,t)\text{d}x\text{d}c\text{d}t=\int\int\mathbb{I}_{x<c} f(c)\text{d}c\left\{\int f(x,t)\text{d}t\right\}\text{d}x$$

Comment: As expressed, your joint distribution is _not available_ as the separation between groups 1 and 2 is not spelled out.

Comment: @whuber and Xi'an: Thank you for your suggestions. The group 1 and group 2 indicator follows a Bernoulli(0.5) distribution. So $f_X(x)=\int_0^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{3}e^{-T/3}dT+\int_0^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{T-1}\dfrac{1}{1.5}e^{-T/1.5}dT$ will give me the marginal density of $X$ and then I can find $\mathbb{P}(X<C)$ like I mentioned in my question? Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: That second integral is logarithmically divergent.